# Android studio -> firebase tool keeps loading

Tags: flutter, android-studio, gradle, firebase-assistant

[what I see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K1PXj.png)

I have been waiting for over half an hour but the firebase assistant just won't show

I'm trying to get this view, but it won't load
[what I want to see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SlxPx.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its been very late but since  no one answered hope it will be helpful for someone.

Most of the time it happens if you switch from native Android project to flutter project or flutter to native project. To resolve this issue simple goto Settings> Plugins and search for firebase and remove all three plugins by unchecking them. Press apply and restart Android studio. Then after restarting goto plugin page again and add all three firebase plugin again and restart.
Thats it. It should be working fine

Comment: not working for me